# How to read from a file and add non duplicate numbers to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am reading a file that has hundreds of numbers (which are repeated) from 1 to 1000. I wanted to create a list of all the unique numbers in the file. The way I am doing it (see the attached code), any number after 9, i.e. 10 and above are being ignored and therefore not stored in the list.

```
TID = 0
items = []
f = open(dataset_name, 'r', encoding="utf8")
for row in f:
    TID = TID + 1
    for item in row:
        if item not in items:
            items.append(item)
```

Comment: If you read all numbers into a list, then use set(mylist), a set object of **unique** numbers will be returned.

Comment: @S3DEV it seems to be a problem with the way I am reading from the file. The numbers are being read as characters and not integers. Therefore, using set(mylist) causes the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you iterating over *each digit* in any number, which are still strings when you read them? So relevant part should be

```py
seen = []
...
for line in f:
    if line not in seen:
        seen.append(line)
```

There are better data structures you can use for checking if an item has been seen though, but in this case it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Note that this solution populates `seen` with strings ending with a newline (`\n`), not integers.

Comment: Yes. If this is a homework, didn't want to do everything here ;)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the `for item in row:` loop is causing your code to look at individual characyers, not each line as a number.
For data this small, a simple solution is to read all of the data at once, i.e.

```
With open('jutska.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    itemlist = f.read().split()
    TID = len(itemlist)
    items = set(int(item) for item in itemlist)
```

If you didn't need the count of lines (`TID`), you could use

```
With open('jutska.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    items = set(int(item) for item in f.read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have one iterator too many: `row` is a line in the file, and

```
for item in row:
```

will iterate over the characters in the line.

Also Python has set data structure for this purpose, I believe you can do this:

```
TID = 0
items = set()
f = open('jutska.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8")
for row in f:
    TID = TID + 1
    items.add(row.strip())
```

Note the use of `strip` to get rid of the newline at the end, and conversion to `int`.